# Elixir Phoenix handle get request with parameters

Tags: elixir

I have defined a router which looks like this:

```
get("/api/cars", CarController, :cars)
```

In this way inside the `cars` function in `CarController` I am parsing all there `params` that are passed with the `get` request. My `cars` function now is using a `case` statement so if there is some parameter provided, do something. My question is how I can parse a parameter name in the router, for example if I receive a get request like this `/api/cars?type=coupe`
how can I match that on the `get` router since I want to handle it separately instead of using the `cars` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short, I don't think you can match query_params in the router, that's up to the controller action handling the route.
So in this case you can pattern match the query_params in your controller actions:

router.ex

```
get "/api/cars", CarController, :cars
```

car_controller.ex

```
defmodule CarController do
  use MyAppweb, :controller

  def cars(conn, %{"type" => type} = params) do
    ...
  end

  def cars(conn, params) do
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Just to add to this, you can pattern match on the specific vehicle as well. `%{"type" => "coupe"}` instead of getting it in a variable and then having to match one it.